# Django User model and multiple model one to one relationship issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have two model Doctor and Patient having many to many relationship.
Both Doctor and Patient is users of my system, so i want to relate it with User module using one-to-one relationship. Doctor model have another relation with Hospital by many-to-many.

Below is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from datetime import date


class Doctor(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='/uploads/photos', default='/uploads/photos/doctor_default_photo.gif')
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    educational_institute = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    experience = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)


class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    disease = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField('date of birth')
    doctors = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor, through='Appointment')

    def patient_age(self):
        today = date.today()
        year, month, day = map(int, self.dob.split('-'))
        return today.year - year - ((today.month, today.day) < (month, day))


class Appointment(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
```

But, when I run the migrate command I get following error.

> psycopg2.IntegrityError: column "user_id" contains null values

Comment: Have you tried dropping your database and migrating it again?

Comment: After running new migration, it saying > You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to doctor without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

Comment: Doesn't sound like you dropped you DB. Could you try that?

Comment: @RodrigoDela it works after droping db. Thanks a lot.